# Analysing programs by hand

Tags: python, code-analysis, diagram

Not sure if this is the best place to ask this, but here goes.

For an exam, I'll have to analyse short pieces of code by hand, to determine the output (if any). Here's an example:

```
def f2(x, y):
    if not x > y:
        return "Red"
    else:
        return "Blue"

def Test(x):
    if x < 0:
        p = f2(2, 4)
    else:
        p = f2(4, 2)

    print(x**2, p)

Test(5)
```

The output for this snippet is `25 Blue`, which I correctly asserted by following the progression of the variables. So I can follow the logic of the program. But is there an easy way, perhaps by way of a diagram or flowchart, that is commonly used to assess the output of a code, or to perform a 'dry run' on paper? Or do people just 'follow the variables'?

Comment: `if not x > y:` => simplify as `if x <= y` that's already better...

Comment: @Jean-Francois-Fabre I appreciate that the code is not as simple as it could be, but that code was given as an example of what I might have to analyse. The idea is to follow the logic, which I can do. I just wondered if there was a 'standard' flowchart or diagrammatic way of following the variables.

Comment: What is the difference between a 'dry run' and 'following the variables'?

Comment: @ScottHunter my thinking to go through that code was:
`x == 5
else is True
p is assigned the results of f2 with x = 4 and y = 2)
f2 return "Blue" then prints x**x and whatever p is, which comes from f2`
I just wondered if there was a diagrammatic way to show my thinking.

Comment: Honestly, a diagram or flowchart may be *more* confusing than the code. But I'm willing to be proven wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Code trace:](http://users.csc.calpoly.edu/%7Ejdalbey/101/Resources/codetrace.html)

> A code trace is a method for hand simulating the execution of your code in order to manually verify that it works correctly before you compile it.   It is also known as a "code trace" or "desk check."

**How to Code Trace**

1. Draw a table with variable names across the top, program lines down the side, and assign a column for output
2. Progress through the program as you'd expect the program to
3. When a variable is assigned a value or the variable's value is manipulated or changed, record that value in the appropriate location according to variable name and line of execution. (This keeps the code tracing clear and organized, making it easier to double check)
4. Continue tracing through the program until the program would terminate as the computer